# Double MongoDb Version

Tags: mongodb

Problem with MongoDB Version

I installed Mongo Db follow this Link

http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-mac-os-x/

After i updated with Brew

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-04-28T10:49:46.475+0200 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2197 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Foo.local
2014-04-28T10:49:46.475+0200 [initandlisten]
2014-04-28T10:49:46.475+0200 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2014-04-28T10:49:46.475+0200 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.0
2014-04-28T10:49:46.475+0200 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2014-04-28T10:49:46.475+0200 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-04-28T10:49:46.476+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-04-28T10:49:46.477+0200 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-04-28T10:49:46.477+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-04-28T10:49:46.477+0200 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2014-04-28T10:49:46.477+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now

➜  ~  mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
```

but if i do this:

```
> use foo
switched to db foo
> use foo
switched to db foo
> foo.version()
2.4.9
```

How can I clean my double Installation?
I want 2.6.0

Comment: One way to do this would be to uninstall mongo with `sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen
sudo apt-get autoremove` and then to install the new version. And why are you installing mongo based on description from some guy (mkyong) on the forum? Do you really think he knows better than official guys from mongo?

Comment: I have no idea why you didn't follow the official documentation on installing MongoDB? Most likely this is a case of two differently named packages or, by the looks of it, you are running MongoDB manually and then running it from service.

Comment: @SalvadorDali i use Mac

Comment: @monkeyUser can you try to uninstall everything on mac? I do not really know how to do this there, I am ubuntu/pc user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@monkeyUser,

Running two different MongoDB instances is not an issue per-se provided they use different data directories. In your case, looks like you have two MongoDB installation with same data directory configured for both. If you intend to keep both the instances you'll need to change the dbPath for one of them to point at some other directory.

If you do not intend to run two instances and only the latest instance, uninstall the previously installed instance using same steps from the blog post but executing them in reverse order (bottom up) and in inverted sense i.e. if blog has a step to create a directory /data/db, you would execute this steps as "deleting the data directory /data/db". Once you have removed one of the instances, second instances should come up fine.